# C++ How to correctly use threads with a while loop

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm new to threads but I've been reading in to it for the past few days and I'm now trying to implement it in a actual example.

I have a GUI class which on click of a button should start a thread. My implementation is following:

```
void Interface::on_startButton_clicked()
{    
    theDetector.start();    
}
void Interface::on_stopButton_clicked()
{    
    //not sure how to stop the thread
}
```

The Detector class then has the following code:

```
void Detector::start()
{
    thread t1(&Detector::detectingThread, this);
    t1.detach();
}

void Detector::detectingThread()
{
    isActive = true;

    while (isActive){
       //run forever and do some code
       //until bool is set to false by pressing the stop button
    }
}
```

I have the feeling that this isn't the correct way to do this. If I detach the thread I can't stop it via the boolean and if I join it right after my GUI freezes as suspected. 
What would be the correct way of doing this example?

Comment: What do you mean you can't stop it via a boolean?

Comment: You simply can't detach threads, and try to join them afterwards.

Comment: @chris He probably found out that compilers optimizes loads away... I give it 10 minutes until someone suggests volatile (which is NOT the solution)

Comment: Well, it should be an `atomic_bool` if it's being set by another thread so you don't do a concurrent read and write.

Comment: @chris yes I was getting 'invalid parasmeter passed to runtime' while using normal bool, my bad. So If I use atomic_bool and keep the rest like it is, is this an efficient and smart way of doing this example? I'm not sure if detaching it is so smart... as I said i'm still new to threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TheDetector` should have a `std::unique_ptr<std::thread> pThread;` and a `std::atomic<bool> halt;`.

`Start` should do nothing if there is a `pThread`.  If not, `halt=false; pThread.reset(new std::thread(&Detector::Task, this));`

Do not detach -- that is rarely a good idea.

In `Stop`, set `halt=true;` then `if (pThread) { pThread->join(); pThread.reset(); }`

In `Detector::Task`, loop `while (!halt)`.

If the code in `Task` is more complex and a single loop might be too long to wait for UI respose, you'll want to defer `join` until a different method.

You'll also want to add `Detector::~Detector()` to halt/join/reset the task.

Comment: Thank you! I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by "Start should do nothing if there is a pThread". You want me to check if the thread is running, correct? how would I do this

Comment: @isADon, If it's running, that means `pThread` has a value (since you set `pThread` when starting the thread), so `if (pThread)` will execute the next statement.